# Why does adding .Wait() to my Task sometimes allow the Task to use the main thread?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I'm trying to understand how asynchronism works, but there's one case that I've simplified to its maximum and I can't find any explanation for it.

On a project mvc asp.net framework 4.6 :

```
...
public class Test {
    public static void Work(int id) {

        if (id == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId) {
            Debug.WriteLine("******************************");
            Debug.WriteLine("***     BOOOMMMM !!!!!!!   ***");
            Debug.WriteLine("******************************");
        }
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        Task.Run(() => { Test.Work(id); });

        return View();
    }
...
```

when I execute the code above :

```
if (id == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
```

is never verified. DoWork() runs on another thread than my main one. There for me it's normal that's what I've always understood in the course of my readings.

But if I put a Wait on Task.Run

```
Task.Run(() => { Test.Work(id); }).Wait();
```

sometimes it's another thread than the main one and sometimes it's not, and I don't understand.

[Here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) it is written:

> Task.Run starts a task on the thread pool to do the calculations. The
>   ASP.NET thread pool has to deal with (unexpectedly) losing one of its
>   threads for the duration of this request.

Okay in his example there is no Wait(), but what difference does it make, Wait() is called after Work() anyway so Work() should always have the same behavior whether there is a Wait() or not.

If anyone can give me an explanation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Tasks run on a scheduler. When you Wait or await the calling thread might be selected to do other work. Like the task it is waiting on.

Comment: Tasks are not threads, but they might run on another one.

Comment: But this is not a real-world problem. When you Run a task on another thread you shouldn't care about on which thread. You sometimes care about the thread the caller will continue on.

Comment: `async` in C# isn't synonymous with threading, instead it creates an event stack which can be fulfilled by any thread

Comment: [`TaskScheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.tryexecutetaskinline) is allowed to inline task in current thread if task is not yet started and current thread synchronously wait for task.

Comment: *Wait() is called after Work() anyway* That is not true. `Work()` is only scheduled to be executed some point in the future. There are no guaranty it actually will be executed before `Wait()`.

Comment: This *is* documented in [`Task.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait): "If the current task has not started execution, the Wait method attempts to remove the task from the scheduler and execute it inline on the current thread"

Comment: Different to the question, but I presume you know the correct thing to do here is to make your action `async` and `await` the `Task` if you want the result not use `.Wait()`?

Answer (score 2):

The TPL can inline tasks into the current thread when you are waiting. This can happen if the task has not started on another thread. It is a performance optimization.

[It is a very controversial feature that injects subtle bugs into applications.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2454) Essentially, any wait on a task can run arbitrary code nondeterministically.